# Java EE RESTFull web services - JSON cycling

Tags: json, web-services, jakarta-ee

i'm new in developing Java EE web applications and I'm trying to develop simple component that allow people to register and login in browser or via smart phone. I use netbeans 7.3 and glassfish server. I need to implement some web services, but i don't have any previous experience with doing that in Java.

firt i did normal web page, using JavaServlet as controller, JPA pages as views and EJB classes as models. Everything works fine, without any problem.

But now i'm trying to implement mentioned web services using JSON objects. At firts I used NetBeans function to generate corresponding classes from entities. When testing with "Test RESTful web service" function, netbeans generates page where i can try all implemented web services. When I try application/XML GET/POST methods, they work fine. But when i switch to application/JSON, something goes wrong.

for example, when i call getUserByID(int id) expecting result as XML representation of User, function returns good result:

```
<user> 
  <groupsCollection> 
    <groupName>administrator</groupName> 
    <id>1</id> 
  </groupsCollection> 
  <id>1</id> 
  <password>21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3</password> 
  <username>admin</username> 
</user>
```

but doing same with expecting result as JSON object results in cycling:

```
{"id":1,"username":"admin","password":"21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3",
"groupsCollection":[{"id":1,"groupName":"administrator","userCollection":[{"groupsCollection":[{"id":1,"groupName":"administrator","userCollection":[{"groupsCollection":[{"id":1,"groupName":"administrator","userCollection":[{"groupsCollection":[{"id":1,"groupName":"administrator","userCollection":[{"groupsCollection":[{"id":1,"groupName":"administrator","userCollection":[{"groupsCollection":[{"id":1,"groupName":"administrator","userCollection":[{"groupsCollection":[{"id":1,"groupName":"administrator","userCollection":[{"groupsCollection":[{"id":1,"groupName":"administrator","userCollection":[{"groupsCollection":[{"id":1,"groupName":"administrator","userCollection":[{"groupsCollection":[{"id":1,"groupName":"administrator","userCollection":[{"groupsCollection":[{"id":1,"groupName":"administrator","userCollection":[{"groupsCollection":[{"id":1,"groupName":"administrator","userCollection":[{"groupsCollection":
```

... cycling goupsCollection (group collection is list of groups where user belongs.

My User model is defined as:

```
public class User implements Serializable {
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "userCollection")
    private Collection<Groups> groupsCollection = new HashSet();
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

   constructors, geters, seters ...


    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "entities.User[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

    public Collection<Groups> getGroupsCollection() {
        return groupsCollection;
    }

    public void setGroupsCollection(Collection<Groups> groupsCollection) {
        this.groupsCollection = groupsCollection;
    }

    public void addGroup(Groups group) {
        this.groupsCollection.add(group); 
    }

}
```

So my question is, what should i do to get proper result when expecting it as JSON object. If any details needed, feel free to ask. thanks for every answer.

update: group entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "groups")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Groups.findAll", query = "SELECT g FROM Groups g"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Groups.findById", query = "SELECT g FROM Groups g WHERE g.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Groups.findByGroupName", query = "SELECT g FROM Groups g WHERE g.groupName = :groupName")})
public class Groups implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "group_name")
    private String groupName;
    @JoinTable(name = "users_groups", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "group_id", referencedColumnName = "id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
    @ManyToMany
    private Collection<User> userCollection = new HashSet();

    public Groups() {
    }

    public Groups(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Groups(Integer id, String groupName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.groupName = groupName;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getGroupName() {
        return groupName;
    }

    public void setGroupName(String groupName) {
        this.groupName = groupName;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<User> getUserCollection() {
        return userCollection;
    }

    public void setUserCollection(Collection<User> userCollection) {
        this.userCollection = userCollection;
    }

    public void addUser(User user){
        this.userCollection.add(user);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Groups)) {
            return false;
        }
        Groups other = (Groups) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "entities.Groups[ id=" + id + " ]" ;
    }

}
```

Comment: Cant you put the `Groups` Entity? I want to see the relationship between this classes

Comment: i did now. group can have many users and user can be assigned to many groups

Comment: are you using jackson? JSON has a problem with circular dependencies. One or those lists you need to annotate with @JsonIgnore if was applicable.